# Will not run after dieing while driving

Tags: chevrolet, starting, malibu

My 2004 Chevrolet Malibu just died while driving and won't start back up. It acts like there's no fire. I put in new plugs, new coil pack, and new control module on top of the coil pack, but it still turns over but won't start. I checked fuel pressure and it's fine. What could wrong?

Comment: If you disconnect a plug wire and ground it with a screwdriver do you have spark? I am thinking crank sensor???

Comment: @mikes - I'm thinking you might be right, but I believe if the crank sensor dies, it will throw a code. To Nathan, have you had the codes read on the car? (And crap if I didn't edit out the year of the car while it was in the title and didn't put it in the body ... sorry about that.)

Comment: @Paulster: I put it back. You know you can  view the edit history, right?